# I want a custom < title > using header() in PHP

Tags: php, html, header, title

Standing on the shoulders of giants, I have successfully cobbled a script using header() to publish pdf documents on my intranet,

My display code:

```
<?php
require_once "includes/IniFile.php";
include_once "includes/process.php";
$MyData['ini'] = IniFile::getSettings();
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
   { $fn = $key; }
$fn = str_replace("|sp|"," ",$fn);
$fn = str_replace("|dt|",".",$fn);
$ed = explode('!',$fn) ;
$MyData['ini']['pathMask'] = str_replace('|DEPT|', dptdir($ed[1], $MyData['ini'] ['departments']), $MyData['ini']['pathMask']);
$MyData['ini']['pathMask'] = str_replace('|FLDR|', subdir($ed[2], $MyData['ini'] ['folders']), $MyData['ini']['pathMask']);
$fn ='';
$file = $MyData['ini']['pathMask'].$ed[0];
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$fn.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
@readfile($file);
?>
```

All works well, but I would like the new page containing the .pdf to have a < title > that corresponds to the document name being published.

Is this possible?

Thanks - Chris.

Comment: The page does not contain the PDF; it *is* the PDF. There is no `<title>` anywhere or the possibility of one.

Comment: Some browsers will probably save the PDF and not display it in the tab.. But for those which do, maybe having the PDF in an iframe / regular frame will let you control the frame container title

Comment: The PDF file itself contains title and author information, some PDF browser plugin might show that in the browser's title bar. This shuld be set inside the PDF document ...

Comment: You could output a normal html page with your custom `<title>`, and then have an iframe inside THAT page to display the pdf, assuming the user has in-browser pdf display enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of throwing out the headers you should render a normal page and embed the PDF in an iframe. In that way you can have your title and the PDF is still inline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My great title for the PDF</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;

height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <iframe src="yourpdfname.pdf"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be what OP wants, but boy is this unfriendly to the user and just a redirect to request yet another resource, adding even more traffic, while not displaying the address to the PDF in the address bar. You'll only loose trust from visitors once they see this practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you first open the PDF with the Zend/PDF library, you can modify the contents of the pdf, including title and other meta related information.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-set-info.php